# Problem installing java in Ubuntu 20

Tags: java

i tried to install java using the following :

```
apt install default-jre
```

but when i want to see the version using :

```
java -version
```

it says :

```
apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72, or
apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.8+10-0ubuntu1~20.04
apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~20.04
apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless  # version 13.0.3+3-1ubuntu2
apt install openjdk-14-jre-headless  # version 14.0.1+7-1ubuntu1
```

i run the installation command again it again :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
default-jre is already the newest version (2:1.11-72).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and when i try to run the following :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

i got this :

```
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java because link group java is broken
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/bin/java with a link
```

and the same keep happening over and over .

i had no problems during installation and all ok when i run a program that depend on java or run the java -version it is not working .

regards

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by going to the path:

```
 /usr/bin/java
```

and there  i found a file with the name

```
 "jdk-14.0.2_linux-x64_bin.deb"
```

removing the java folder form there fixed the issue and now everything is ok .

Regards